# netstat: command not found

Tags: command-line, 21.10, lamp, xampp, netstat

I installed `xampp` to run a server as part of a guide, but it wasn't working. After trying to run it from command line, I got the following output:

```
$ sudo ./xampp start panel
Starting XAMPP for Linux 8.1.6-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
/opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
fail.
XAMPP:  Starting diagnose... 
XAMPP:  Sorry, I've no idea what's going wrong. 
XAMPP:  Please contact our forum http://www.apachefriends.org/f/ 
Last 10 lines of "/opt/lampp/logs/error_log":
tail: cannot open '/opt/lampp/logs/error.log' for reading: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting MySQL.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
ok.
```

The line of interest is `netstat: command not found`

I tried to do `sudo apt install netstat`, but it's not found. Alternatively, is `netstat` part of another Ubuntu package I should be installing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Found out I'm supposed to use `sudo apt install net-tools` for this

Answer (score 6):

By my opinion. Netstat was replaced "ss", which is default installed.